# Why is the distribution of the sum of the values on two dice bell-shaped and symmetric if two uniform dist is triangular distribution?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, sum, dice, triangular-distribution

Why is the distribution of the sum of the values on two dice bell-shaped and symmetric if two uniform dist. sum is triangular distribution via Irwin-hall distribution?

Comment: Hm. It isn't, it's triangular. Try a simulation, tabulate the results, and plot a histogram.

Comment: This exact question (at least your first sentence) is answered in a recent [3 Blue 1 Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeJD6dqJ5lo).

Comment: @jkj What leads you to the premise that it's bell shaped? (I presume you read that claim somewhere, but it's incorrect; it might be worth identifying where the notion came from in the question). The distribution is discrete triangular; it's easy to compute it and see that the left half increases linearly and the right half decreases linearly (and symmetrically to the left half)

Answer (score 2):

About 50 years ago, I did a simulation of this for a middle school science project. This was before computers, so I had to roll the dice by hand and tabulate by hand as well. Then I compared my results to the results predicted by the laws of probability.

They were very close!

The shape is triangular. Only with a low N would it look like a bell. And it's pretty straightforward to show the results (I will leave the answers in /36 for clarity):

- 2 or 12 ... 1/36  (each)
- 3 or 11 .... 2/36
- 4 or 10 .... 3/36
- 5 or 9 .... 4/36
- 6 or 8 .... 5/36
- 7   ........6/36

I didn't win. Some kid who showed pictures of his molting snake won. One of the teachers told me they didn't understand my project.

You can try simulating it yourself, but I recommend using a computer - rolling dice is BORING.